# Grafana Dashboard selector is stuck

Tags: selector, grafana, provisioning

It could be on a different dashboards. Now I have this issue on 707 and 1860 ones. I provision them via Docker volume, but it behaves the same way when I import them manually.

[image: The first item for DEV is always selected and it's not possible to change it]

So on this picture, the first item for DEV is always selected and it's not possible to change it

Comment: What version are you running? And yes I have experienced the same issue in the past. But I have not been able to make it reproduce-able in a way I could attach to a bug report.

You can try to type the datasource manually. This fixes it for me and I can select them again.

Comment: I have just downgraded it to 7.1.5 and it works again